# storing thumbs up/down in database or session?

Tags: cookies

I want to add feature to rate (only thumb up or down) the comments. Since there will be lots of comments therefore I think storing the thumbs up or down for each comment will increase lots of data in the database. Is there an alternatuve and efficient way to avoid storing in database, for example by storing temperarily with cookies or session (as long as browser is open)? 
Thank you for your expert views. If cookies/session is efficient, I'll highly appriciate any example how i can store following data temporary, for example,
user_1 thumb_up  comment_1
user_1 thumb_down comment_2

**Edit:** 
Sorry, I think I was not very clear about my question. Is it efficient to store Only total number of the thumbsup/down. I don't want to store the IP address or the username of every user in database.

Answer (score 0):

Um, do you want to have thumb up/down counts to only show for one user? I would suggest you consider that use case before trying to store it in a cookie...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my original post that I only want to store total number of thumbs up/down. I dont want to store ip or username of each user who thumbs up or down. Is it better to store those data or it is better without? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Storing that sort of data in the session or cookies will mean that you only track which posts the user has given a thumbs-up to, and only if they keep using the same browser. This seems fairly pointless, since usually such UI elements are only interesting when they show what people think in aggregate.

Assuming that you track thumbs up/thumbs down as integer columns or similar in your database, this is not going to increase your resource use all that much.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in my original post that I only want to store total number of thumbs up/down. I dont want to store ip or username of each user who thumbs up or down. Is it better to store those data or it is better without? Thanks.